# Spectra and cohomology theories

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory

I know that every generalised (Eilenberg-Steenrod) cohomology theory defines a spectrum (in the sense of Lewis-May), and vice-versa. I also know that maps between spectra are richer than maps between cohomology theories (due to the existence of phantom maps).

How unique is the/a spectrum representing a cohomology theory?

In particular, are Eilenberg-MacLane spectra unique up to weak equivalences? (An Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum for the abelian group $A$ is a spectrum representing ordinary cohomology with coefficients in $A$.)

Comment: it's unique and this is just the yoneda lemma: if you have a natural isomorphism between two representable functors it is induced by an isomorphism between the representing objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not understand how to make this argument work on the level of spectra.

Comment: What is unclear? That cohomology theories also define functors on spectra? That the induced map $E^*(X) \to F^*(X)$ is also an isomorphism for some cohomology theories $E, F$?

Comment: I apologize for my claims that this is easy; questions of this nature rarely are. The last point in my comment above is resolved by the Milnor lim^1 sequence for generalized cohomology of spectra, but the statement that you can upgrade some equivalence $E \to F$ of cohomology theories to a map of the corresponding $\Omega$-spectra seems subtle. You can get a map of pointed spaces $\Omega^\infty E \to \Omega^\infty F$, but you need to show that this is an infinite loop map.

Comment: More Yoneda shows that you can get something like "map of N-indexed spaces $f_k: \Omega^{\infty - k}E \to \Omega^{\infty - k} F$ so that $\Omega f_k$ is homotopic to $f_{k-1}$", but that is not the same as an infinite loop map. Something more needs to be shown.

Comment: That's precisely how my question arose.

Comment: Maybe it's worth knowing that the uniqueness of (some) Eilenberg-MacLane spectra (as $\Omega$-spectra) is proved in an answer to another one of my questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319919/why-is-pi-fh-mathbbf-p-h-mathbbf-p-the-mod-p-steenrod-algebra

Comment: I sincerely apologize for being so blithe about it (though, in the future, it is probably good to add things like this to the post itself if you already know them - for the sake of fools like I!). I hope you get a good answer. I still think it should look like the sketch I provided, but the higher homotopies are not clear to me.

Comment: Well, I do not think that you are too far off (at least for EM spectra). I found a proof of their uniqueness in the Alaska notes. It boils down to proving that EM spectra define cohomology theories of spectra. Then, of course, you can use the Yoneda lemma, as you suggested! I haven't found anything on the general case though.

Comment: Have you checked Switzer's book, *Algebraic Topology*? Section 9 is devoted to the representation theorems, although since I'm not too familiar with the text myself I couldn't say if it includes a discussion of exactly what you are looking for or not.

Comment: I can also (possibly) recommend you Rudyak's book *On Thom Spectra, Orientability, and Cobordism*. Section 3 is devoted to phantom maps and in particular 3.3 discusses the representability theorems. Maybe Theorem 3.20 (iii) and Theorem 3.21 are the statements you are looking for?

Comment: I had a discussion about this in the homotopy theory chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48336826#48336826) which may be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to answer my question!